# How to connect twitter with Joomla 1.6

Tags: authentication, twitter, joomla1.6

im trying to connecting joomla 1.6 with Twitter Account, does anyone know the way to solve it? or where i can find the tutorial?
Thanks and Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not opposed to it, there are extensions available.
http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/twitter-display/

Comment: thanks for the link! now, i have successed developing twitter authetication - joomla, with modified one of extension from that link. Thanks and regards :)